# Modelling increasing variation

Tags: regression, variance, model

I was wondering about the following modelling problem, but I can't think of an appropriate way to solve it.

Imagine two variables without a linear relationship, but a one increases, the variability of the other increases.

In this case, while there is no relationship between the variables, we might assume we don't know anything, but we do know that a lower score in x means the range of values for y is much smaller. 
So it not true that we know nothing. So it seems like we could build a model with some explanation for how variation changes, which is a better model that no relationship

Below is some R code showing what I mean. The application I have in mind for this is slightly more complicated, but I am unsure if I can even pass this hurdle.

What kinds of methods are available to solve this kind of problem?

```
set.seed(123)
df = data.frame(
  y = rnorm(1000, mean = 0, sd = 1:1000),
  x = 1:1000 
)
plot(df$x, df$y)
```

[image]

Comment: I don't see a question mark, and I can't tell what the question is.  Could you phrase the question in the form of a question?  Do you have sample/toy information/data for input, variables, and output?  I just can't tell what you are looking for in plain language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible model would be the Generalized Additive Models for Location, Scale and Shape (GAMLSS). Take a look at [the `gamlss` package for R](https://cran.r-project.org/package=gamlss). There is a very good introduction to the package ([Stasinopoulos & Rigby, 2007, *JSS*](https://doi.org/10.18637/jss.v023.i07)).

In the present case, we could model the mean as constant and the variance as linearly increasing with `x`:

```
> library(gamlss)
> gamlss(y~1,sigma.formula=~x,data=df)
GAMLSS-RS iteration 1: Global Deviance = 14878.17 
GAMLSS-RS iteration 2: Global Deviance = 14877.73 
GAMLSS-RS iteration 3: Global Deviance = 14877.73 

Family:  c("NO", "Normal") 
Fitting method: RS() 

Call:  gamlss(formula = y ~ 1, sigma.formula = ~x, data = df) 

Mu Coefficients:
(Intercept)  
      2.761  
Sigma Coefficients:
(Intercept)            x  
   4.712020     0.002613  

 Degrees of Freedom for the fit: 3 Residual Deg. of Freedom   997 
Global Deviance:     14877.7 
            AIC:     14883.7 
            SBC:     14898.4
```

Comment: Perfect. If interpret this code correctly, we have a model for predicting y and a model for predicting sigma? It is not entirely clear to me from this what work ~x is doing. Is it more strictly written as sigma ~ x? I think yes, but I will read the texts!

Comment: Precisely. GAMLSS allows you to specify models for the first four moments. Here, I specify that the mean is constant (`y~1`) and that the standard deviation depends linearly on `x` (`sigma.formula~x` - you could remove the intercept from that formula with `-1`). Unfortunately, the notation is not entirely consistent. You could do similar things for additional parameters if you had a different distribution than the default normal. Do read the paper, it's very enlightening, with a couple of detailed examples.